# Creating a directory containing dictionary files SHELL

Tags: linux, shell, dictionary

I have to create a directory, containing 10 dictionary files from 0 to 9, using words from a file, just like this:
In my file, for example:

```
012  
032  
..  
943  
234  
978
```

And I must have in file 0:

```
012            
032  
file 2: 234  
..    
file 9: 978  
        943  
(one word per line)
```

I tried this:

```
 file=$1
    mkdir dictionary
    cat $file | while read line;do
          for i in {0..9};do
               var=$( echo $line | head -c 1 ) #trying to get fist character
               cd dictionary
               if [ "$var" -eq "$i" ]
               then
                       if [ -e $i ] #checking if file exists
                       then
                            $line > $i
                       else
                            touch $i  
                            $line > $i
                       fi
            fi
   done
cd ..
done
```

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Missing a quotation mark in the line `if [ "$var" -eq "$i ]`?

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: Also, if you want to **write** a line, `$line` isn't a command that'll do that. `printf '%s\n' "$line"`, perhaps (or `echo "$line"` if you don't care as much about avoiding subtle bugs).

Comment: You're also hitting [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) due to a [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html); use `done <"$file"` to end your loop, instead of `cat $file |` to start it.

Comment: As it is, though, there are a whole bunch of separate bugs here, rather than being properly one-issue-to-a-question. Use [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) and the links given above to fix the low-hanging problems, `bash -x yourscript` or `set -x` to figure out more precisely what's being run as your script executes, and then compose a question around a single isolated issue from that effort if you still have problems.

Comment: (BTW, there's no need to `touch $i` before you redirect to a file -- `>"$i"` will create the file named by the contents of the variable `i` on its own. (Without the quotes, behavior isn't quite as well-defined).

Comment: You might also see [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for an introduction to doing native string manipulation in bash. `var=${line:0:1}` is a much more efficient way to get the first character of a string. The bash-hackers [page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) is another good reference describing the relevant syntax.

Comment: (By the way -- debugging scripts, using shellcheck, and many other useful topics are covered in the StackOverflow [`bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info); consider giving it a read).

Comment: (Also, "creating a dictionary" is *usually* a reference to creating a data structure equivalent to what other languages call hash maps or, well, dicts; in bash, these are "associative arrays". Someone else who ends up here because they see the title is liable to be looking for the content covered in [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays)).

Comment: I notice you've fixed *one* use of `$line` where you actually want `echo "$line"` [err, *partially* fixed it, since you're still missing the quotes], but there are still at least two more.

Comment: Oh, yes. In my script (in Ubuntu) actually i have used var=${line:0:1} as you said. i'm trying to do step by step to fix it all. You helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: I did it! Thank you.